# Save a Struct element in an Array or Element Array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct, element

Hello i am really new to programming and have to programm a C++ Code for separate chaining and for that i have to use a struct and a constructor called ADS_set.

My struct looks like this:

```
struct element {
 key_type key;
 size_type *nextElement = nullptr;
 Mode mode {Mode::free};
};
```

The constructor has to look like this:

```
ADS_set(){
table=new element * [N];
for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
{
  table[i].key=0;
  table[i].mode=Mode::free;
  table[i].nextElement = nullptr;
}
}
```

My question is how do i have to declare my table outside of ADS_set that it accepts all this lines. Is it an array or array of elements?

Comment: I concur. You should read up on your C++ syntax. Specifically study hash tables.

Comment: @gavsta707 Please tell me more about the C++ syntax for hash tables. I'm curiour.

Comment: @rubenvb I presume they meant [std::unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)